# Is it better to use 'contains' or 'get' to find an element?

Tags: javascript, cypress

I'm writing a login.spec.js, and at this point, I'm checking the availability of further login options links (*I still didn't have the chance to create a specific label to test these elements, as Best  Practices suggest*):

```
<span id="DDB_Social_List">
    <span>Further login options:</span>
    <a href="..."><span><label class="icon soclgn facebook"></label><strong>Facebook</strong></span></a>
    <a href="..."><span><label class="icon soclgn paypal"></label><strong>Paypal</strong></span></a>
    <a href="..."><span><label class="icon soclgn microsoft"></label><strong>Windows Live</strong></span></a>
</span>
```

I implemented two different ways of checking the availability of these links:

```
cy.get('span#DDB_Social_List > a:nth-child(2)').should('have.attr', 'href','...')
```

and

```
cy.contains('Facebook').should('have.attr', '...')
```

Which way is better and why? I have completely no idea.

Comment: BTW there's a variation `cy.contains('my-selector', 'my-content')` combing the two commands. In your case it would be `cy.contains('span#DDB_Social_List > a', 'Facebook')`. Why is it better? The list of links might change next week, say Twitter is added at the top, so `a:nth-child(2)` needs to be changed to keep the test green - a **fragile test**.

Comment: Oh, I like that! Thanks for the contribution

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd suggest to use `.get()` if you know what the appropriate selector for your element is. If you'd use a simple `.contains('Facebook')` and there is another element which contains the word Facebook, you're risking cypress will match that element. I guess if several elements match, it depends on the order in the DOM tree. In such case, you'd need to be sure about the order of the elements and use `.first()` or `.last()` commands (https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/first.html)

Using `.get()` is conditioned by you knowing the selector(tag, class, attributes etc). It's more decisive and selects the exact element you specify with the selector. Use get and avoid the risk of matching another element with the same text.

You can read more on the usage of those two here:

- get - https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/get.html#Syntax
- contains - https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/contains.html#Syntax

In your particular case, if there was a div above your list (e.g. `<div> Facebook is amazing!</div>`) `cy.contains('facebook')` would match it and the attribute you're looking for would probably be different and therefore would your test fail.